# I want to reset the modalafter closing it, but it's not working

Tags: jquery

I have a modal box which is as follows:

```
<div class="modal-coupon-code">
        <center class="show-code"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#couponcode<?php echo $result->id; ?>">Show Coupon Code</button></center>

         <div class="modal fade" id="couponcode<?php echo $result->id; ?>" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title"><img src="http://www.image.png" class="img-responsive" width="350"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                  <div class="popup-code-block">
                  <span class="code-txt" data-type="html" data-model="couponCode"><?php echo $result->coupon_code; ?></span>
                  <span class="copy-btn" data-type="attribute" data-attr-name="data-clipboard-text" data-model="couponCode" data-clipboard-text="<?php echo $result->coupon_code; ?>">COPY CODE</span>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I am using it for showing code, when a user click on `COPY CODE`, it is copied to clipboard and the backroundcolor as well as text is changed to green and `COPIED` respectively. But when I close the modal, I want to reset it. What I have tried is as folows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.copy-btn').on("click", function(){
        value = $(this).data('clipboard-text');
        //console.log(value);
        var $temp = $("<input>");
          $("body").append($temp);
          $temp.val(value).select();
          document.execCommand("copy");
          $temp.remove();
          $('.copy-btn').css("background-color", "green").text("Copied!");
          $(modal).on("close", function(){ //I am getting problem here
            $(this).css('background-color', '').text('');
          })
    })
})
```

There are three ways to close the modal. First oneis using close symbol, second one is using close link.Andthied one is by clicking outside the modal box, which also closes the box. How can I reset the modalbox text and color changed in these three cases.

Answer (score 0):

To listen for when a modal closes, use this `$( "#modal" ).on( "hide.bs.modal", function(e) { });`

To reset the background color and remove the coupon code, use:

```
$( "#modal" ).on( "hide.bs.modal", function(e) {

    $( ".code-txt" ).html( "" );

    $( ".copy-btn" ).css( "background-color", "" );
    $( ".copy-btn" ).text( "" );

});
```

You have not defined the `modal` variable in your question, so I used "#modal"